# Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am beginner in spring and in my console based project i am using spring with hibernate.I was stuck with the following error for about a day.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1126)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:619)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:616)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:616)
at com.hbtemp.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl.insertStudent(StudentDaoImpl.java:22)
at com.hbtemp.test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:25)
```

I searched for this error in the web but i couldn't find the solution,so please help me with some concept

Model Class:Student.java

```
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private int rollNo;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}
public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}
```

StudentDaoImpl.java

```
public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate){
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}

@Override
public int insertStudent(Student student) {
    hibernateTemplate.save(student);
    return 0;
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id = "dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_jdbc_template"></property>
    <property name = "username" value = "root"></property>
    <property name = "password" value = ""></property>
</bean>

<bean id = "mySessionFactory" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"></property>
      <property name = "mappingResources">
         <list>
             <value>student.hbm.xml</value>
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name = "hibernateProperties">
          <map>
             <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></entry>
             <!-- <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update"></entry> -->
             <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value = "true"></entry>
             <entry key="checkWriteOperation" value = "false"></entry>
             <entry key="current_session_context_class" value = "thread"></entry>
          </map>
      </property>
</bean> 

<bean id = "hibernateTemplate" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
     <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "mySessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id = "studentDaoImpl" class = "com.hbtemp.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl">
     <property name = "hibernateTemplate" ref = "hibernateTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

student.hbm.xml :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "com.hbtemp.model.Student" table = "student">
    <id name = "id" column = "ID">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name = "firstName" column = "FirstName"></property>
    <property name = "lastName" column = "LastName"></property>
    <property name = "address" column = "Address"></property>
    <property name = "rollNo" column = "Roll_NO"></property>
</class>
```

TestClass.java

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    StudentDaoImpl studentDaoImpl = (StudentDaoImpl)context.getBean("studentDaoImpl");

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId(2);
    student.setFirstName("Prakash");
    student.setLastName("Gautam");
    student.setAddress("Bhaktapur");
    student.setRollNo(434);

    int status = studentDaoImpl.insertStudent(student);
```

If i write a code **hibernateTemplate.setCheckWriteOperations(false)** inside **insertStudent method** it works fine............but my question is...is it good practice or not ? If it isn't good pratice please recommend the good pratice

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and resolved it by adding @Transactional annotation to the method where we have used hibernate template calls for database-related operations.

```
@Override
**@Transactional**
public int insertStudent(Student student) {
    hibernateTemplate.save(student);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add " "in spring configuration file, this will work for sure.